# Vuex store not persist 'state' when I refresh or navigate?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Using the following example, why does Vuex store not persist 'state' when I refresh or navigate?

I've created a login that stores users state information using Vuex. This works, and I can view the user "this.$store.state" However, when I navigate to another page or refresh the "state" resets, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vuex doesn't persist state automatically. You can use the `vuex-persistedstate` package to achieve this (https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate).